# How to display data gotten from a qr scanned object to the browser

Tags: angular

I have an app where I am working with qr-scanner. The contents gotten from the qr code logs on the console, but I want to find a way to display my result on the browser. These are my codes

**Component .ts file**

```ts
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.qrScannerComponent.getMediaDevices().then((devices) => {
      console.log(devices);
      const videoDevices: MediaDeviceInfo[] = [];
      for (const device of devices) {
        if (device.kind.toString() === 'videoinput') {
          videoDevices.push(device);
        }
      }
      if (videoDevices.length > 0) {
        let chosenDev;
        for (const dev of videoDevices) {
          if (dev.label.includes('front')) {
            chosenDev = dev;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (chosenDev) {
          this.qrScannerComponent.chooseCamera.next(chosenDev);
        } else {
          this.qrScannerComponent.chooseCamera.next(videoDevices[0]);
        }
      }
    });
    this.qrScannerComponent.capturedQr.subscribe((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

**Template .html**

```html
    <qr-scanner
    [debug]="false"
    [canvasWidth]="1080"
    [canvasHeight]="720"
    [stopAfterScan]="true"
    [updateTime]="500"
    >
    </qr-scanner>
```

**data on the console**

```
MECARD:N:Joca;ORG:jocak;ADR:panaroma;TEL:3521738899;EMAIL:gypsyplanet@gmail.com;NOTE:Harmony over balance;;
```

Comment: You need to add a property on your component to assign the `result` to. Then output the result in the component's template via `{{ result }}` or however it makes sense to display. If you're wanting to show the individual values, you're going to need to split the `result` on `;` first, then split the remaining values on `:` to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.ts file

```
import {
Component,
ViewChild,
ViewEncapsulation,
AfterViewInit,
OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';

import { QrScannerComponent } from 'angular2-qrscanner';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild(QrScannerComponent, { static: true })
qrScannerComponent: QrScannerComponent;
title = 'dropdown';
dataGotten = [];


  ngOnInit() {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.qrScannerComponent.getMediaDevices().then((devices) => {
  console.log(devices);
  const videoDevices: MediaDeviceInfo[] = [];
  for (const device of devices) {
    if (device.kind.toString() === 'videoinput') {
      videoDevices.push(device);
      }
   }
  if (videoDevices.length > 0) {
    let chosenDev;
    for (const dev of videoDevices) {
      if (dev.label.includes('front')) {
        chosenDev = dev;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (chosenDev) {
      this.qrScannerComponent.chooseCamera.next(chosenDev);
    } else {
      this.qrScannerComponent.chooseCamera.next(videoDevices[0]);
    }
    }
    });
    this.qrScannerComponent.capturedQr.subscribe((result) => {
    this.dataGotten = result;
    console.log(result);
    });
    }
    }
```

.html

```
   <div class="container">
   <qr-scanner
   [debug]="false"
   [canvasWidth]="1080"
   [canvasHeight]="720"
   [stopAfterScan]="true"
   [updateTime]="500"
   >
   </qr-scanner>
   <div>
   <p>{{ dataGotten }}</p>
  </div>
```